# update categories in emails using python

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to update categories of emails available in one of the data frame using below code.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

i = 0

for message in messages:
       try: 
        message.Categories = output.iat[i,2]
       except:
           message.Categories = 'No Category'
       i = i + 1
```

Below script used to move updated emails from inbox to another folder and then remove to inbox

```
donebox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[20]

def delay(time):
    for j in range(time):
        j=j+1


i = 0

while (messages.Count > 0):
    print(i,messages.Count)
    message = messages.GetLast()
    message.Move(donebox)
    delay(1000000)
    i = i + 1


messages = donebox.Items

i = 0

while (messages.Count > 0):
    print(i,messages.Count)
    message = messages.GetLast()
    message.Move(inbox)
    delay(1000000)
    i = i + 1
```

In outlook updated Categories from output dataframe for emails are able visible only once email selected. Is there any option which can refresh outlook and categories will be updated automatically. Please advice.

Comment: I found some solution but not sure whether it is more efficient , I have moved emails from inbox to another folder and after that I removed those emails to original inbox folder, then I was able to view changes in categories in emails. I have added additional script in my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone who cant save changing of non-selected mail Categories property by Python:

```
mail.Categories='Red category'
mail.Save()
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me!

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch    

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Inbox")

messages = folder.Items

for i in range(messages.Count):
    messages[i].GetInspector()
    messages[i].Categories = 'Purple Category'
    messages[i].Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one category needs to be assigned to each email, [dmitrii.kotenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10439676/dmitrii-kotenko) has provided the solution.

If you need to append more than one category, pass the categories as a string separated by commas

```
mail.Categories = "category1, category2, category3"
mail.Save()
```